# HashMap / TreeSet combination inconsistency

Tags: java, collections

This works ok:

```
Map aMap;
aMap = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

This does not compile:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> aMap;
aMap = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

Error message:

```
Compilation failed (26/05/2014 11:45:43) Error: line 2 - incompatible types - 
  found java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.TreeSet<java.lang.String>>
  but expected java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>
```

Why?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Since in the first example `aMap` is defined without using generics, it does not perform the generic type validation (but it shows a warning!). The second example defines the types of `aMap`, so a proper check of types can be done (google for wildcards in generics).

Comment: What's issue to this ?

Comment: Basically for the first code the compiler tells you "I hope you are sure your code works properly, because I cannot tell"... in the second one, the compiler is sure that your definition is wrong.

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev the issue is my understanding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one works because you use a raw type (without generic) so you can put any type of map in there.

The second one doesn't work because [a `XXX<Set>` is not a `XXX<TreeSet>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

So you need to choose between:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> aMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
//or
Map<String, TreeSet<String>> aMap = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

And in both case you will be able to write:

```
aMap.put("abc", new TreeSet<>());
```

The main difference is when you get an item from the map, with the former construct you won't have access to the `TreeSet` specific methods.

Finally, with Java 7+ you can omit the generic information on the right hand side and the compiler will determine it automatically for you:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, TreeSet<String>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: +1 yes - I'm using 7+ so might be safer to just use the diamond notation ... seems strange to pick a non-specific notation to make things safer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
    Map<String, ? extends Set<String>> aMap;
    aMap = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

Because the Set's generic must not be the same than TreeSet's generic.

Comment: Worth noticing that you won't be able to put any key-value pair in the map (except a key mapped to null).

Comment: Using a more intelligent compiler this might work, you can write a FR if you like.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

+1 to Peter's answer, TreeSet implements SortedSet which extends Set.

```
Map<String, ? extends Set<String>> aMap;
    aMap = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

will work fine.

Comment: +1 is this from a Java site? can you add a link to the source?